# Finding SQLite version linked to a binary in Linux

Tags: c, linux, sqlite

I have a software package which is using sqlite library. For this purpose, I link the sqlite.a with the final object file to create the final package/binary.

Is there way through which once a binary is created, it can be confirmed which version of SQLite has been linked with that binary? I ask this because I have multiple version of SQLite on my build environment (3.6.20, 3.7.7.1). I have observed an issue in one of the executing binary and I don't know which version of library I had used to make that binary.

This is a linux (CentOS5) environment I am working on.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the binary itself to log or declare what version of SQLite it's using. The binary knows this at compile time from the SQLite defines. Since the linking is static, the version built against is the same as the version used.

Comment: Thanks for response. I don't think that would be possible that the primary reason I ask this is because I have modified by build environment and I need to know what it was for this particular binary. Nevertheless, this certainly can be a future-implementation idea :) - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find the version that the library was compiled against by doing something like `strings ./foo | grep "3\.[67]\.".`  Unfortunately, if you didn't use any of the functions from sqlite that would output this string in your code (like `sqlite3_libversion()`), they might not have been copied over by the linker and might not be present.

Comment: I used objdump and hexdump to view whether such a information is part of the binary thus created, but nothing fruitful came out. Nevertheless, thanks for the comment.